# Double logs while getting the volume of System ring using ContentObserver

Tags: android, contentobserver

I am trying to get System ring volume change using the content Observer. Using this volume integer number I would like trigger another java file.

I succeeded using the below code but the problem is I am getting two logs always. I am trying to  differentiate the previousVolume and ChangedVolume. I am not why am I getting to logs inside change method? Good thing about this is that the values are not changing?

Here is the code I have tried:

```
public class VolumeChecker extends ContentObserver 
{
 int previousVolume;
 Context context;

public VolumeChecker(Context c, Handler handler) 
{
    super(handler);
    context=c;

    AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    previousVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

}

@Override
public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() 
{
    return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) 
{
    super.onChange(selfChange);

    AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);

    Log.e("changed", "Volume"+currentVolume);
 }
 }
```

And registering the obersever -from service as:

```
Volume = new VolumeChecker(this,new handler());
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true, Volume );
```

Does anybody know why it is logging twice inside onChange part?

Comment: Also include code to register observer